# C#, Process.Start hide?

Tags: c#, process

```
public static void Main(string[] args){
    SearchGoogle("Test");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}

static void SearchGoogle(string t){
    Process.Start("http://google.com/search?q=" + t);
}
```

Is there any way to hide the browser, so it won't pop up??

Comment: Mr Noob: If you dont want the browser to start up then where is it supposed to show the web page?

Comment: If you hide the browser then how will you show the results? ;-) . What excatly is the requirement?

Comment: It looks like this is what you're looking for... [Calling Yahoo with C#](http://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/howto-rest_cs.html)

Answer (score 11):

Something like:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("http://google.com/search?q=" + t);
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps you are looking for [ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx) ?

Answer (score 5):

If you want the results instead of a Browser you can use the WebClient class.

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string html = client.DownloadString("http://google.com/search?q=" + "Test");
}
```

Comment: If this is what he needs, definitely the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd need to do this, but hey, everyone has a reason. Here's `ProcessStartInfo` code that does exactly what you need:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(string.Format("http://google.com/search?q={0}",t));
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.UseShellExecute = true;

Process.Start(psi);
```