# How to start Process hidden?

Tags: c#, process

I start a Console Application via ProcessStartInfo and process.Start(). I want to hide the black window.  Here's my code:

```
string output = "";
//Setup the Process with the ProcessStartInfo class
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "C:\\WINNT\\system32\\cmd.exe";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

//Start the process
Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ? CreateNoWindow = true ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide console window from Process.Start  C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377423/hide-console-window-from-process-start-c-sharp)

Answer (score 40):

The final answer is

```
 ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
 psi.FileName = ....
 psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
 psi.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
 psi.Arguments =...
 psi.UseShellExecute = false;
```

**`psi.CreateNoWindow = true; // <- key line`**

Comment: CreateNoWindow did the trick for me where WindowStyle had no effect. I'm redirecting standard output anyway and can now avoid the empty window.

Answer (score 38):

Try This:

```
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Comment: That will do the trick. Only add that it has to be set before calling `Process.Start(startInfo)`.

Comment: doesnt work, but... you get an error it simply show the black window? I need more info. :D

Comment: I tried your code and I'm getting and error related with pipes, not with your actual question. If I replace FileName with a .bat file, It run without problems and no black windows are shown.

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Process p = new Process();
....
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.Start();
```

Comment: This answer adds no new knowledge to existing answers.