# how to hide cmd prompts window pop up in Vb?

Tags: vb.net, popup, hidden, process.start

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("net", "use" \server\z)

how do I hide the pop up window when the processes start ? thank you

Comment: Possibly look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377423/hide-console-window-from-process-start-c-sharp.

Comment: Drag another window ontop of it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Startinfo property.  See if something like this works:

```
            Dim NewProcess As New Process()
            NewProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False 
            NewProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "net"
            NewProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "use \server\z"
            NewProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
            NewProcess.Start()
```