# how to start process with hidden window

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
string d = "-f image2 -framerate 9 -i E:\\REC\\Temp\\%06d.jpeg -r 30 E:\\REC\\Video\\" + label1.Text + ".avi";

//string d = "-f dshow -i video=\"screen-capture-recorder\" E:\\REC\\" + label1.Text + ".flv";
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "E:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = d;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;

if (!proc.Start())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error starting");
    return;
}
proc.WaitForExit();
```

When it runs the `ffmpeg.exe` is there like this:

[image]

My question is how to hide this window?

Comment: `CreateNoWindow` should be true.

Comment: Also do note that if you're redirecting standard output, you *have* to read it (typically asynchronously, but it's not necessary in your case).

Comment: it basically do one job is to convert images to video i execute this code only if there are images so it will almost work every time, but i don't want it to run on front of the user it need to be hide

Comment: i removed them and i still not hidden

Comment: thanks @Luaan i did make it true , and it did hide

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide console window from Process.Start  C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377423/hide-console-window-from-process-start-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

You need the following combination of settings:

```
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

And that's it.

The reason being that the key setting is `CreateNoWindow` which has to be `true`. But `CreateNoWindow` only has any effect when `UseShellExecute` is `false`. That's because `CreateNoWindow` maps to the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` process creation flag passed to `CreateProcess`. And `CreateProcess` is only called when `UseShellExecute` is `false`.

More information can be found from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx):

> **Property Value**
>
> **true** if the process should be started without creating a new window to contain it; otherwise, **false**. The default is **false**.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> If the UseShellExecute property is true or the UserName and Password
>   properties are not null, the CreateNoWindow property value is ignored
>   and a new window is created.

Answer (score 1):

This on keeps the all processes in same console window. no allow to open an new one`

```
Process process = new Process();

 // Stop the process from opening a new window
 process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

// Setup executable and parameters
  process.StartInfo.FileName = @"E:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe"

 //Optional
  string d = "-f image2 -framerate 9 -i E:\\REC\\Temp\\%06d.jpeg -r 30 E:\\REC\\Video\\" + label1.Text + ".avi";
 process.StartInfo.Arguments = d;

 // Go
  process.Start();
```