# How do i start a process in c# calling net.exe without having a window pop open?

Tags: c#

I am starting a process to disconnect a network drive, but it always pops up a command prompt window.  It just flashes by quickly and disappears, but i would like to configure it so the window doesn't open at all.  Any ideas?

Here is the c# code I'm currently using:

```
private void btnDisconnectNetwork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process DisconnectDrive = new Process();
    DisconnectDrive.StartInfo.FileName = "Net.exe";
    DisconnectDrive.StartInfo.Arguments = @" Use /d Q:";
    DisconnectDrive.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    DisconnectDrive.Start();
}
```

Comment: _"Any ideas?"_ - Perform the network drive disconnection _in code_ rather than spawn a child process.

Comment: i would like to do that, but i don't know how.  I'm kind of a newbie.  can you point me in the right direction for doing in code?

Comment: [Would this code which shows how to map the drive and unmap it dynamically at runtime do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808226/reconnecting-a-disconnected-network-drive)

Comment: No, i will have the user select a UNC from a combo box and from that i will map the "Q:" drive letter to that UNC.

Comment: Although spawning a child process is not the ideal way to do it, I would still like to know if there is a way to do this through Net.exe without showing the prompt window that pops up.

Comment: I think i found what i was looking for:
            DisconnectDrive.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to start process with hidden window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635340/how-to-start-process-with-hidden-window)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will also work:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace processexample {
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo();
        si.CreateNoWindow = true;
        si.UseShellExecute = false;
        si.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\net.exe";
        si.Arguments = @"/help";
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = si;
        p.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

You have to set the CreateNoWindow and UseShellExecute in StartInfo.