# WPF Check if python installed on system

Tags: c#, python, wpf, cmd

My wpf application calls a python script to generate output which is later displayed in the UI. To avoid crashing of the application if python is not installed on user's system, I need to perform a check. Currently I have achieved that using the following

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
start.FileName = @"cmd.exe"; // Specify exe name.
start.Arguments = "python --version";
start.UseShellExecute = false;
start.RedirectStandardError = true;

using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardError)
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                MessageBox.Show(result);
            }
        }
```

This does the job but causes a momentary appearance of the cmd black window which is highly undesired. Is there a workaround to achieve this or a fix to avoid the appearance of the window?

Comment: Maybe add start.CreateNoWindow = true; ?

Comment: Possible dubplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377423/hide-console-window-from-process-start-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
start.FileName = @"cmd.exe"; // Specify exe name.
start.Arguments = "python --version";
start.UseShellExecute = false;
start.RedirectStandardError = true;
start.CreateNoWindow = true;

using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardError)
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                MessageBox.Show(result);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you could check the registry for the default value of the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Python.exe`

This is arguably more reliable than just trying to run python.exe, since the Python installer doesn't always update the `PATH` variable.

Comment: how can it be checked? I have a lot but in vain

Comment: Do you know how to read the registry programmatically? Google "C# read registry".

Comment: I have Python Installed and running on my machine but I don't have it's Entry in App paths. But I can see the Python's Entry under Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python