# Check if python is installed

Tags: python, c#, windows, winforms, cmd

I am trying to get the installed version of python from a pc using c# (as a part of a WinForms app).
I'm trying to do so by creating a new subprocess following these two threads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22694028/wpf-check-if-python-installed-on-system) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020109/why-does-process-startcmd-exe-process-not-work) , but none seems to work...

I've tried  changing the fields of the process constructor the other way around to:

```
UseShellExecute = true
RedirectStandardOutput = false
CreateNoWindow = false
```

and it seems that the `Arguments` does not even passed to the subprocess so nothing will be outputted..(it just opens a cmd window regularly)

What am i missing?

This is the current code

Its a rough and initial code, and will change once i get the output messages..

*both methods seems to start the cmd process but it just gets stuck and does not output anything, even without redirection.

```
private bool CheckPythonVersion()
    {
        string result = "";

        //according to [1]
        ProcessStartInfo pycheck = new ProcessStartInfo();
        pycheck.FileName = @"cmd.exe"; // Specify exe name.
        pycheck.Arguments = "python --version";
        pycheck.UseShellExecute = false;
        pycheck.RedirectStandardError = true;
        pycheck.CreateNoWindow = true;

        using (Process process = Process.Start(pycheck))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardError)
            {
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                MessageBox.Show(result);
            }
        }

        //according to [2]
        var proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Arguments = "python --version",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        };
        proc.Start();
        while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            // do something with result
        }

        //for debug purposes only
        MessageBox.Show(result);
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(result);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Python is `python.exe`, so you can run it directly. You don't need `cmd.exe`. It just makes things more complicated.
2. You redirect `StandardError`, but that's not where the version information is written to. Redirect `StandardOutput` instead.
3. This whole approach will only work if Python has been added to the `%PATH%` environment variable. If it was installed without that, Python will not be found.

With 3. in mind, the code which works for me:

```
void Main()
{
    var p = new PythonCheck();
    Console.WriteLine(p.Version());
}

class PythonCheck {
    public string Version()
     {
        string result = "";

        ProcessStartInfo pycheck = new ProcessStartInfo();
        pycheck.FileName = @"python.exe";
        pycheck.Arguments = "--version";
        pycheck.UseShellExecute = false;
        pycheck.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        pycheck.CreateNoWindow = true;

        using (Process process = Process.Start(pycheck))
        {               
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Python 3.9.7
```

Comment: 1. i missed that. noted.
2. i did tried that with no success (using cmd though)
3.all python installations around here are automatically installed with the %PATH% env.variable added, so i currently don't worry about that at the. 
but for future reference (if you are willing of course), how can i take care of that?

Thanks!

Comment: @ALWS34: you can't really work around the %PATH% problem, because one can have dozens of Python versions installed on disk. Basically, every virtual environment is a copy of Python. Finding all of them would require a totally different approach

Comment: This just returns an empty string for me, even though python is installed and in the command line "python --version" works fine. Why could that be?

Comment: @MeisterderMagie: There are several possibilities. a) Setting %PATH% in CMD with `set` will not affect other programs, unless they are started from that same CMD. b) setting %PATH% for the user will not set %PATH% for other users. Make sure you run the program as the same user or set %PATH% for all users. c) If you set %PATH% using `setx` (not `set`), not all programs may respond to the notification of changed environment variables. So, how would you debug this. And IMHO that makes a quite good question on its own. I would debug this using SysInternals Process Monitor and VoidTools Everything.