# How can I hide a window having his handler on c#

Tags: c#, winapi, process

I need to hide a window that is generated using `Process` class.

I made this procedure

```
_process = new Process()
            {
                EnableRaisingEvents = true
            };
_process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
_process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
_process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
_process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
_process.StartInfo.FileName = "app.exe";

_process.Start();
```

I need to hide a window that is generated for this process. Probably a child window of it.

I need a way to hide all child windows that a process call can generate.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377423/hide-console-window-from-process-start-c-sharp

Comment: Okay, but you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: CreateNoWindow can only apply to console mode apps.  ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden is routinely ignored by GUI apps since that creates a zombie that the user can only close with Task Manager.  Contact the owner of the program for support.

Comment: What can I do if I don't have suppport of the app? Any suggestions.

Comment: @codeVillagerCU0 Alter your requirements to something that you're capable of accomplishing.

Comment: I find a way of do this using pinvoke and the functions of the winapi. I don't know if that is a good practice but works.