# How to hide the command robocopy window in C#?

Tags: c#, robocopy

How to hide the command robocopy window in C#?
I tried so:

```
startInfo.Arguments = "\"" + source + "\" " + "\"" + fold + "\"" + formats + "  /s /R:1 /W:5 /MT:12 /njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns /np /nfl";
```

this code doesn't work - the command window opens. I want that the command window not to open and robocopy worked "silently".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide console window from Process.Start  C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377423/hide-console-window-from-process-start-c-sharp)

Comment: It's not the same thing ! With Robocopy is not working !

Comment: Did you already try omitting all the logging switches? Did you also try setting `RedirectStandardOutput`, `UseShellExecute` and `CreateNoWindow` accordingly? If so, please update your post to make clear what you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Set the **[WindowStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processwindowstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** property.

```
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Comment: This option , too, I tried , it does not work with robocopy