# How to get the output from a Process?

Tags: c#, cmd

So this is my current code:

```
 private void StartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Download = "placeholdercommand"

        string CWD = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();        

        Process process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

        startInfo.Verb = "runas";                           ///launch as admin
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";                     ///launch cmd
        startInfo.Arguments = "/k cd /d " + CWD + "&" +     ///navigate cmd to CWD (/k = return)
                              Download + "&" +              ///give Download order to cmd
                              "exit";                       ///exit cmd

        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
    }
```

Now I would like to make the cmd window invisible and display the cmd workings in real time in my c# window. How would I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide console window from Process.Start  C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377423/hide-console-window-from-process-start-c-sharp)

Comment: did you try setting CreateNoWindow?

Comment: process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Process.start: how to get the output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291912/process-start-how-to-get-the-output)

Answer (score 0):

Use this to hide

```
info.WindowStyle=ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Get the output

```
while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    string Line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
}
```