# Hide git-bash window calling from C#

Tags: c#, git-bash

I am writing a application in C# to access git-bash on run a script in git-bash. I need to hide git-bash.exe.

I have tested the following code but it does not work:

```
Process process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-bash.exe",
                UseShellExecute=false,
                Arguments = "-c ./script.sh",
                WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            }
        };

        process.Start();
```

It opens the git-bash and runs the script successful but it does not hide thew window. I have already tested all suggested methods in other posts but still no luck.

Comment: Did you check this question and answers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377423/hide-console-window-from-process-start-c-sharp/26303805

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez That post is for command window. I am trying to hide git-bash.

Comment: since git bash runs in a command window, give it a try and let me know, you are alson using process.Start as in that question

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez I have tried it exaxtly like the post you sent, not working. It works for curl.exe but not for git-bash.exe

Comment: please update your question mentioning what you have tried - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting CreateNoWindow option to false?

Comment: Yes, I have already tried that, no luck.

Comment: again, please update your question to include what you have already tried in order to help you better