# how to let .NET 5 app to access directories except root?

Tags: directory, permissions, .net-5

I have a client api (.NET 5.0) running on client's computer which designed to handle client side database and file processes. This api access all folders during development by adding staticfiles and directorybrowser middlewares but it does not access directories after publishing on client side. Api files are placed under c:\inetpub\wwwroot. IIS is used to serve this api. Windows OS with domain system is used on client PC.

I need to let this api access directories given by the user at runtime. Giving permission to a specific folder is not an option since it will be any directory selected by the user.
I tried WCF service and it accessed all directories on client side without any configuration.

What configuration or things solve this problem. I want to give folder freedom to user  :)

Answer (score 0):

I found an option as follows:
I created a program which is started via start up when the user logged in . thus program starting with user privilages. this program starts service in silence mode with https://stackoverflow.com/a/14765016/10026505 . api service gets the user's permissions automatically. it can access any folder that user can